# What is the name of the function to create dataframe from text in R, with each element being separated by space or tabulation?

Tags: dataframe

I know that it's possible but I can't remember the name of this function

```r
# Does this function exist ? For a character element formatted more or less as follows
function_readText(
"col1   col2
    1   2
    3   4")

  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    3    4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `read.table`

```r
read.table(textConnection(
 col1 col2
    1   2
    3   4"), header = T) 

  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    3    4
```